# Reflection: get invocation object in static method

Tags: java, reflection, static, static-methods

Is it possible to get an object that invoked static method in this method?

I have this code:

```
class A{
    static void foo(){
    }
}
A a = new A();
a.foo();
```

Can I get instance `a` in method `foo()` ?

Comment: Where is the constructor `A()`?

Comment: If you don't define a constructor the A() is the one used by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your code isn't good as a programmer.

It is because static methods are class-level methods and should be called without any instance of class.

Recommended approach :

```
class A{
    static void foo(){
    }
}
A.foo();
```

> Can I get instance a in method foo() ?

Nope, you can't. [Because foo() is declared as static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134237/why-cant-you-use-the-keyword-this-in-a-static-method-in-net). So you can't use this inside that method, since this contains a reference to the object that invoked the method.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, there is no instance object for a `static` method (static methods do not operate on a specific object, they are defined within a class purely for namespacing) -- so **no**.

Answer (score 0):

No is impossible...the static method don't have the reference, you have to pass it reimplementing the method as:

```
class A{
    static void foo(A theObject){
    }
}
A a = new A();
A.foo(a);
```

and is better don't call the static method from the instance of the object

Answer (score 0):

No; that's what `static` means.
The compiler actually completely ignores the instance.

Use an instance method.