# Static property using INotifyPropertyChanged. C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying create a static property where `INotifyPropertyChanged` will update any changes made to a `DataGrid` `ComboBox` that I am binding to.

I am getting this error,

> Error CS0026 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static
>   method, or static field

Through my searches I came upon this [Why can't you use the keyword 'this' in a static method in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134237/why-cant-you-use-the-keyword-this-in-a-static-method-in-net), but even after going through everything I still can't figure out how to get this to work.

But, anything I change only negates that I am trying to make a static property with `INotifyPropertyChanged`???

My code:

```
private static List<string> _nursingHomeSectionListProperty;

public static List<string> NursingHomeSectionListProperty
{
    get { return _nursingHomeSectionListProperty; }
    set
    {
       _nursingHomeSectionListProperty = value;
       NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And Property changed handler

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And the below code is how I am using the property changed handler for non static properties,

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
```

Comment: I don't get why you need static propery in your model, but the first argument of the `Invoke` is the sender. and a simple `new object()` will do

Comment: Also, why are you using delegate. Invoke and name your raise method Notify... and not On?

Comment: @Sefe Because of the `?.` operator. The name of the method is irrelevant.

Comment: Don't use ?. in these cases. To resort to Invoke is an overuse of this operator.

Comment: @Sefe I guess you don't know what `?.` is. Writing `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` is the current up-to-date way to write this. You should do it exactly like this.

Comment: @Clemens: the On... convention is best practice and for a good reason. Unless you consider all naming conventions irrelevant.

Comment: @Sefe I've seen `Notify` more often than I've seen `On`. I guess even the WCF `svcutil` creates `NotifyPropertyChanged` methods. Besides that it is just an implementation detail, and entirely irrelevant here. For the null-conditional operator, here is the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: @Clemens: you guess wrong. And just because of the operator's existence this way does not become up to date. It's like saying that after anonymous methods were introduced the up to date way of writing methods is to make them anonymous.

Comment: @Sefe Just checked it. My `svcutil` creates `RaisePropertyChanged` methods, a third "best practice". As said, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass `null` instead of `this`:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
{
    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

See [this blog post](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) for details about static property change notification.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well, this helps me so much.

Comment: OK, I am having a issue, your link does not show how to use the `Static Member` , `StaticPropertyChanged`. This throws an error in the XAML, saying it cannot be resolved. Unfortunately the link does not touch on this, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The post also shows how to bind to a static property. Probably ask a new StackOverflow question and provide the details of the error.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is in the link it shows `Two Approaches to Change Notification` , it only shows how to bind the first approach for binding static properties. I am using the second approach, which ,from what I can tell the link does not show how to do this. Or am I missing something? Cheers

Comment: It's just two approaches to *implement* static property change notification. Binding to such a static property is the same for both.

Comment: OK, but the link shows this in the XAML, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and not this, `UpdateSourceTrigger=StaticPropertyChanged`, `PropertyChanged` won't do anything if the method uses `StaticPropertyChanged`. That is my understanding of this.

Comment: It is a common misundestanding, but `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with how the property change notification of the source property is implemented. It just controls how the source property is updated by the Binding and is only effective if there is data flow from target to source, e.g. in a TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding. Do not set it at all.

Comment: I can't understand how that works. If I am using `NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();` method, should I not be pointing to `StaticPropertyChanged` as that is the event in the method? Not `PropertyChanged`

Comment: No, you shouldn't. As said, `UpdateSourceTrigger` is something completely different than what you think it is. You don't have to tell the framework how property change notification is implemented. It detects that out of the box by reflection. Again, do not set UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: OK, so I don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger` at all, that is a first for me, thanks again for the help.

Comment: Well after a month of fiddling around with this, everything finally has clicked. I finally see what you have been trying to tell me. Thanks again for all the explanations, I could not have done it without them. One thing I have noticed that is some instances you need to invoke `INotifyPropertyChanged` on an `ObservableCollection<T>` , which then does not allow the property to be written like this, `public static ObservableCollection<T> foo { get; set; }`. Anyway, thanks again.