# Bind Static Variable using TwoWay binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind a static variable to a calender, but I am getting an error that I need to have a `Path` when using `TwoWay` binding.

There is plenty of examples of binding static variables, but I just can't seem to get any of the examples to work for me.

This this is the property:

```
private static DateTime _vCalenderSelectedDate;

public static DateTime CalenderSelectedDate
{
    get { return _vCalenderSelectedDate; }
    set
    {
        _vCalenderSelectedDate = value;
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is the simplified XAML:

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:StaffShiftManager.ViewModels"

<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding
    Source={x:Static viewModels:ShiftManagerViewModel.CalenderSelectedDate}, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

I tried doing it the way most people are suggesting by adding a path to the XAML, but I just can't get it to work;

```
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding 
    Source={x:Static viewModels:ShiftManagerViewModel.CalenderSelectedDate},
    Path=CalenderSelectedDate,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding expression should look like shown below. Note the parentheses around the path.

```
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding 
    Path=(viewModels:ShiftManagerViewModel.CalenderSelectedDate)}"/>
```

For details, see the [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx#PropertyPath%20for%20Objects%20in%20Data%20Binding) article on MSDN, section *Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified*.

Comment: Hey Clemens, I was sure I tried that way which I got from here http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties. But sure enough, the first one works perfectly. Thanks Did you leave out the `http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties` on purpose?

Comment: I guess the UpdateSourceTrigger was redundant, right?

Comment: I left it in on my example. I will try it without now.

Comment: You are right again, it is redundant. How can that be so? I was sure you always had to specify `PropertyChanged` in the XAML

Comment: For most dependency properties, the [DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.defaultupdatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) value is PropertyChanged. You only have to set UpdateSourceTrigger on a two-way binding if you want to change the default.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure this question is answered completely, I think it is relevant to link to an answer to another related question asked by the same user.

The question above has a line with:

```
NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();
```

I wanted to be able to combine what the user had in their question with the XAML provided in the answer, but needed to know how the notification of a static property changing worked.

I searched and finally found that [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41519441) which has the definition for that:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
{
    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```