# This keyword not able to access object field

Tags: c#, this

```
class school
{
    int a;

    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        school obj = new school();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.a);
        Console.WriteLine(this.a);
    }
}
```

Even though we cannot access instance variables from a static method, here we are doing so by using the reference variable 'obj' and accessing an instance variable. However when we use 'this' keyword, it shows an error that 'this' cannot be used to access instance variable inside static method.
obj contains the address of the object, so it is able to access. Even 'this' points to the instance variable but it still can't access. Does 'this' get the object's address in a different way?

Comment: How is this Java?

Comment: Java and C# share almost a similar syntax. Also, this question is about the 'this' keyword. I'm getting a similar error when I coded this in java but couldn't write the code for both languages over here.

Comment: Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

I found this on Oracle. It seems that 'this' keyword can only access an object when it is used inside a instance method or a constructor.

Comment: Well, a lot of languages have similar syntaxes/features/behaviors, but you don't need to tag all of them.

Comment: I wanted to get all possible answers from a variety of people. Guess that's something wrong, ain't it?

Comment: 'this' does not point to the current object in this case beacause this keyword can not be use in the static method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't you use the keyword 'this' in a static method in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134237/why-cant-you-use-the-keyword-this-in-a-static-method-in-net)

Comment: You can get all possible answers, but it looks like the answer you really want is in C#, so no need to waste other people's time.

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword can be used only in non-static methods of the class

Answer (score 1):

`this` just works on instance methods and refers to current object.

in class body

```
public void printSchool() {
   System.out.println(this.a)
}
```

in main method

```
School s = new School();
s.printSchool();
```

here `this` refers to `s`

Comment: Why doesn't 'this' work inside the main method then, if we can use a reference variable to access an object in the main(), shouldn't 'this' also be able to do so?

Comment: `this` is Implicit parameter of non-static method of class. It can't use in static methods.

Comment: public void printSchool(School this) { // implicit parameter of non-static method.
   System.out.println(this.a)
}

it no means in static methods.

Comment: Well now this is Java. That's why you only tag it Java if you want a Java answer.